# How to use Jquery Tag-it and Algolia instant search autocomplete together

Tags: jquery, algolia, tag-it

I have the working code of Jquery Tag-it to autocomplete code for backend ajax request, Also I found the working code of Algolia search autocomplete, I just want to merge these codes and use algolia autocomplete in the jquery tagit library. I tried to merge them but start getting errors in the console.

Thanks in advance

//jquery tagit code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Using jQuery UI Tag-it</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" integrity="sha512-aOG0c6nPNzGk+5zjwyJaoRUgCdOrfSDhmMID2u4+OIslr0GjpLKo7Xm0Ao3xmpM4T8AmIouRkqwj1nrdVsLKEQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/css/jquery.tagit.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container"> 

        <h2>Add</h2>
        <br>
        <form id="form">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="category">Category  </label>
                <input type="text" name="category" id="category" class="form-control">  
            </div>
      <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary "> 
    </form> 

  </div>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-uto9mlQzrs59VwILcLiRYeLKPPbS/bT71da/OEBYEwcdNUk8jYIy+D176RYoop1Da+f9mvkYrmj5MCLZWEtQuA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/aehlke/tag-it/master/js/tag-it.js"></script>
    <script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    
    $("#category").tagit({
      autocomplete: {
        source: function( request, response ) {
          console.log(request);
          $.ajax({
                url: "/autocomplete",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                  'search':request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (category) {
                      return {
                          label: category.name,
                        
                      };
                  }));
                }
            });
          }
      }
    });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Algolia autocomplete code

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://unpkg.com/instantsearch.css@7/themes/satellite-min.css"
    />
    <title>InstantSearch | Autocomplete</title>
 
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        
<div class="aa-input-container" id="aa-input-container">
    <input type="search" id="aa-search-input" class="aa-input-search" placeholder="Search with algolia..." name="search"
        autocomplete="off" />
</div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/algoliasearch/3/algoliasearch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/autocomplete.js/0/autocomplete.min.js"></script>

    <script>

         (function() {
    let client = algoliasearch('Algolia-app-id', 'Algolia-search-key');
    let index = client.initIndex('categories');
    let enterPressed = false;
    //initialize autocomplete on search input (ID selector must match)
    autocomplete('#aa-search-input',
        { hint: false }, {
            source: autocomplete.sources.hits(index, { hitsPerPage: 10 }),
            //value to be displayed in input control after user's suggestion selection
            displayKey: 'name',
            //hash of templates used when rendering dataset
            templates: {
                //'suggestion' templating function used to render a single suggestion
                suggestion: function (suggestion) {
                    console.log(suggestion)
                    const markup = `

                        <div class="algolia-details">
                            <span>${suggestion.name}</span>
                        </div>
                    `;

                    return markup;
                },
                empty: function (result) {
                    return 'Sorry, we did not find any results for "' + result.query + '"';
                }
            }
        }).on('autocomplete:selected', function (event, suggestion, dataset) {
            console.log(suggestion)
            // window.location.href = window.location.origin + '/shop/' + .slug;
            // enterPressed = true;
        }).on('keyup', function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13 && !enterPressed) {
                window.location.href = window.location.origin + '/search-algolia?q=' + document.getElementById('aa-search-input').value;
            }
        });
})();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

After two days of searching, I found following solution

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Using jQuery UI Tag-it</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" integrity="sha512-aOG0c6nPNzGk+5zjwyJaoRUgCdOrfSDhmMID2u4+OIslr0GjpLKo7Xm0Ao3xmpM4T8AmIouRkqwj1nrdVsLKEQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/css/jquery.tagit.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container"> 

        <h2>Add</h2>
        <br>
        <form id="form">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="category">Category  </label>
                <input type="text" name="category" id="category" class="form-control">  
            </div>
      <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary "> 
    </form> 

  </div>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-uto9mlQzrs59VwILcLiRYeLKPPbS/bT71da/OEBYEwcdNUk8jYIy+D176RYoop1Da+f9mvkYrmj5MCLZWEtQuA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/aehlke/tag-it/master/js/tag-it.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/algoliasearch/3/algoliasearch.min.js"></script>

  <script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

      var client = algoliasearch('your-app-id', 'app-key');
      var index = client.initIndex('categories');

      $("#category").tagit({
        autocomplete: {
          source: function( request, response ) {

            index.search(request.term).then(({ hits }) => {
              response($.map(hits, function (category) {  
                return {
                  label: category.name,
                  
                };
              }));
            })
          }
        }
      });
    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```